# How can I parse repeated HTML elements by their class attribute?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse an HTML file with basically the same tags.

I want to get this output:

> BTC - Bitcoin, BEP20(BSC), Bitcoin(Segwit)
>
> ETH - ERC20, BEP20(BSC), POLYGON, ARBITRUM, AURORA, MATISEVM
>
> USDT - OMNI,TRC20,ERC20,BEP20(BSC),HECO,POLYGON,FTM, AVAX-C ,ARBITRUM,METISEVM
>
> QASH - ERC20

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```html
<div data-v-326d86f4="" class="table-box">
   <table data-v-326d86f4="">
      <tr data-v-326d86f4="">
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">BTC</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="" class="block-chain">
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_box"><span data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_name">Bitcoin</span> <span data-v-326d86f4=""><i data-v-326d86f4="" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="select-list"><span data-v-326d86f4="">Bitcoin</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">BEP20(BSC)</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">Bitcoin(SegWit)</span></div>
         </td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">0.001</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">0.002</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-v-326d86f4="">
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">ETH</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="" class="block-chain">
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_box"><span data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_name">ERC20</span> <span data-v-326d86f4=""><i data-v-326d86f4="" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="select-list"><span data-v-326d86f4="">ERC20</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">BEP20(BSC)</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">POLYGON</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">ARBITRUM</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">AURORA</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">METISEVM</span></div>
         </td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">0.012</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">0.024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-v-326d86f4="">
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">USDT</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="" class="block-chain">
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_box"><span data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_name">OMNI</span> <span data-v-326d86f4=""><i data-v-326d86f4="" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></div>
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="select-list"><span data-v-326d86f4="">OMNI</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">TRC20</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">ERC20</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">BEP20(BSC)</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">HECO</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">POLYGON</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">FTM</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">AVAX-C</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">ARBITRUM</span><span data-v-326d86f4="">METISEVM</span></div>
         </td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">30</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-v-326d86f4="">
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">QASH</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="" class="block-chain">
            <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_box">
               <span data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_name">ERC20</span> <!---->
            </div>
            <!---->
         </td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">513</td>
         <td data-v-326d86f4="">1026</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ... -->
```

I'm using the `HtmlAgilityPack` library without success:

```vbnet
Dim arqHtml As String = "C:\Users\Mattia\Desktop\ready.html"
Dim myHtml As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
myHtml.Load(arqHtml)
Dim myTable As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = myHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
Dim myRows As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = myTable.SelectNodes("tr")
For Each tmpRow As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In myRows
    Dim myCells As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = tmpRow.SelectNodes("td")
    If myCells IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim myToken As String = myCells(0).InnerText
        Dim mySpans As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = myCells(1).SelectNodes("div[contains(@class,'select-list')]/span")
        If mySpans IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim myListBChain As New List(Of String)
            For Each mySpan As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In mySpans
                RichTextBox1.Text += mySpan.InnerText
            Next
            Dim allItensAsString = String.Join(", ", richtextbox1.text)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This returns this output:

> BitcoinBEP20(BSC)Bitcoin(SegWit)ERC20BEP20(BSC)POLYGONARBITRUMAURORAMETISEVMOMNITRC20ERC20BEP20(BSC)HECOPOLYGONFTMAVAX-CARBITRUMMETISEVMEOSBEP20(BSC)ERC20BEP20(BSC)TRC20BEP20(BSC)ZILBEP20(BSC)NEOLEGACYNEON3ERC20POLYGONERC20DAGBEP2BEP20(BSC)FTMAVAX-CERC20BEP20(BSC)ERC20BEP20(BSC)ERC20HECOBEP20(BSC)ERC20HECOERC20POLYGONERC20HECOERC20POLYGONERC20BEP20(BSC)BCHBEP20(BSC)ERC20LOOPPOLYGONBEP20(BSC)FTMAVAX-CMETISEVMERC20TOLERC20METAERC20BEP20(BSC)

How do I make it return the output I want?

Comment: Please post a minimal sample of the HTML to be processed in the question itself.  Externally-hosted content is not suitable for Stack Overflow due to the potential for link rot, but the service you used in the now-deleted link even says "This document will expire in 21 hours", making this question useless after that.

Comment: In the last `<tr>` in the sample, where the first `<td>` contains `QASH`, the second `<td>` does not contain a `<div ... class="select-list">` so `myCells(1).SelectNodes("div[contains(@class,'select-list')]/span")` returns `Nothing`, hence the exception.

Comment: I've just updated the code because I realized that at some rows there is no span, so have to check before go ahead. What you are stating is endeed correct because in this case, the coin QASH support just a single chain so it doesn't need a select-list.

Comment: I think you just need to swap a couple lines: replace `RichTextBox1.Text += mySpan.InnerText` with `myListBChain.Add(mySpan.InnerText)` and `Dim allItensAsString = String.Join(", ", myListBChain)` with `RichTextBox1.Text += String.Join(", ", myListBChain)`.  That won't, however, properly join together (with newline or `,`) the values of `RichTextBox1.Text` for multiple `tmpRow`s.

Comment: Just tried what you suggest me, but the output is still unclear, something like
`Bitcoin, BEP20(BSC), Bitcoin(SegWit)ERC20, BEP20(BSC), POLYGON, ARBITRUM, AURORA, METISEVMOMNI, TRC20, ERC20, BEP20(BSC), HECO, POLYGON, FTM, AVAX-C, ARBITRUM, METISEVMEOS, BEP20(BSC)ERC20, BEP20(BSC)TRC20, BEP20(BSC)ZIL, BEP20(BSC)NEOLEGACY, NEON3ERC20, POLYGONERC20`

Comment: in the case of QASH where there is no select-list it means it support just a single chain so ERC20, like I stated in the output I'm expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002994/how-to-loop-parse-an-html-with-same-classes#comment125518154_71002994) on [the original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71002994/4), in the last `<tr>` in the sample...

```html
<tr data-v-326d86f4="">
    <td data-v-326d86f4="">QASH</td>
    <td data-v-326d86f4="" class="block-chain">
    <div data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_box">
        <span data-v-326d86f4="" class="chain_name">ERC20</span> <!---->
    </div>
    <!---->
    </td>
    <td data-v-326d86f4="">513</td>
    <td data-v-326d86f4="">1026</td>
</tr>
```

...the second `<td>` does not contain a `<div class="select-list" ... >`, so...

```vbnet
myCells(1).SelectNodes("div[contains(@class,'select-list')]/span")
```

...returns `Nothing`, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

As far as building the output you want, first you need to test if such a `<div class="select-list" ... >` element exists...

```vbnet
If mySpans Is Nothing Then
```

If it doesn't, then save the contents of the `<div class="chain_box" ... ><span class="chain_name ... >` element...

```vbnet
Dim chainTextNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = myCells(1).SelectSingleNode(
    "div[contains(@class, 'chain_box')]/span[contains(@class, 'chain_name')]"
)

chainText = If(chainTextNode Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chainTextNode.InnerText), "(unknown)", chainTextNode.InnerText)
```

I added a little extra handling just in case that element doesn't exist or have a value.

If there is a `<div class="select-list" ... >` element, then save the values of its child `<span ... >` elements separated by commas...

```vbnet
chainText = String.Join(", ", mySpans.Select(Function(span) span.InnerText))
' Alternative: chainText = String.Join(", ", From span In mySpans Select span.InnerText)
```

Finally, build and append a new line to your text box...

```vbnet
RichTextBox1.Text &= $"{myToken} - {chainText}{Environment.NewLine}"
```

The complete code looks like this...

```vbnet
Dim arqHtml As String = "C:\Users\Mattia\Desktop\ready.html"
Dim myHtml As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
myHtml.Load(arqHtml)
Dim myTable As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = myHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")

Dim myRows As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = myTable.SelectNodes("tr")
For Each tmpRow As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In myRows
    Dim myCells As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = tmpRow.SelectNodes("td")
    If myCells IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim myToken As String = myCells(0).InnerText
        Dim mySpans As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = myCells(1).SelectNodes("div[contains(@class,'select-list')]/span")
        Dim chainText As String

        If mySpans Is Nothing Then
            Dim chainTextNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = myCells(1).SelectSingleNode(
                "div[contains(@class, 'chain_box')]/span[contains(@class, 'chain_name')]"
            )

            chainText = If(chainTextNode Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chainTextNode.InnerText), "(unknown)", chainTextNode.InnerText)
        Else
            chainText = String.Join(", ", mySpans.Select(Function(span) span.InnerText))
            ' Alternative: chainText = String.Join(", ", From span In mySpans Select span.InnerText)
        End If

        RichTextBox1.Text &= $"{myToken} - {chainText}{Environment.NewLine}"
    End If
Next
```

If you have a very large input HTML file you might consider...

- Appending each iteration's line to a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder)...

  ```vbnet
  outputBuilder.Append($"{myToken} - {chainText}{Environment.NewLine}")
  ```

  ...and then setting `RichTextBox1.Text` once after the loop...

  ```vbnet
  RichTextBox1.Text = outputBuilder.ToString()
  ```
- (Assuming WinForms) Calling [`RichTextBox1.SuspendLayout()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout) before the loop and [`RichTextBox1.ResumeLayout()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout) after the loop

...to improve performance, however, using either or both approaches means `RichTextBox1` won't display any output until the HTML is completely processed.